# N cannot be partitioned into a finite number of arithmetic progressions

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

N cannot be partitioned into a finite number of arithmetic progression with distinct steps except the trivial case $\{1,2,...\}$

The hint told me to consider:
$$\sum_{n\in N}z^n=\sum_{i=1}^r\frac{z^{a_i}}{1-z^{d_i}}$$
and I figured out for some $j$ we have  $a_j=1$, but I don't know how to prove $d_j=1,r=1$

Comment: What is N? The set of natural numbers? If so, then the claim is false, because $\{1,3,5,7,9,...\},\{2,4,6,8,10,...\}$ form a partition.

Comment: @Wojowu sorry , i have corrected the question

Comment: That's a very nice problem. You may want to have a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25313/finitely-many-arithmetic-progressions

Comment: $N$ cannot be a power of $2$.